# Spring+AngularJS Database operations

Tags: angularjs, database, spring, rest

This isn't really a question as much as it is a request. I'm developing a web app using Spring+AngularJS and I'm in dire need of some tutorials. I have generated the most of it with JHipster, but I lack some things I really need.

For example, let's say I have two entities in my database. Category and Review. I have everything generated for loading all reviews in a web page, all categories, deleting, editing etc., but I need a way to get **all Reviews belonging to a certain Category**. I've looked all night for some tutorials that would show me how to do this(maybe I haven't searched right).

Could someone please point out some helpful ones that they know of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is the JHipster mini book, but not sure if they would mention this specific use case.

Basically you just need to do the following:

1. Create a custom repository method on your ReviewRepository which takes a Category parameter that returns all Reviews.

   List findAllByCategory(Category category);
2. Create a new RestController method on the Spring ReviewResource that takes the Category as a HTTP Parameter.

   @RequestMapping(value = "/reviews", params= "categoryId",
           method = RequestMethod.GET,
           produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public List getAllByCategoryId(@RequestParam(value = "categoryId", required = true) Long categoryId) 
   {
           return reviewRepository.findAllByCategory(new Category(categoryId));
   }
3. Modify the query operation on the angular service to take a categoryId param:

   'query': { 
               method: 'GET', 
               params: {categoryId: null},
               isArray: true
           },
4. Invoke the service in your angular controller:

   Review.getAllByCategoryId({categoryId: categoryId}, function(result) {
               $scope.entity = result;
           });